# windows mail client support send mail by commandline?

Tags: windows, email

i want to write batch file and in bash file i want to send mail .. so i need windows mail client support command line to sending email (with attachment)

*note :- i need it also support SMTP username and password

Comment: What version of Bash?

Comment: i want to write my own batch file ... by windows command line

Comment: Do you mean a bash or batch file?

Comment: sorry i mean batch file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I interpreted you question correctly (not an easy task) you want a commandline tool to send emails. The time proven tool for this is [blat](http://www.blat.net/).

Comment: Mr.John do you have a full example about blat ?????

Comment: @Mohammad, click on the word "blat". It's a link that will take you to the product web site, where you will also find all the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [examples on Petri IT Knowledgebase](http://www.petri.co.il/send_mail_from_script.htm).

EDIT: For authentication-support and attachments consider [smtpmail](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/smtpmail.1.asp)

Comment: but i need method support attachment and SMTP username and password

Comment: do you know from whare i can download smtomail or mailx ???? for windows